# Plotly Dash Callback error : Trying to hide Div components

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I am trying to hide input components `Div` after link is clicked.

I have given the Div `id='input_fields'`, so that i can hide it's child components but on `return app1.layout, {'display': 'none'}` I get the following error.

> "Callback error updating display-page.children, input_fields.children"

Class

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    html.Br(),
    html.H1("Interpretation of Financial Statements", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    html.H1("10 year data analysis", style={'text-align': 'center'}),
    html.Div([dcc.Input(id='input-1-state', type='text', placeholder="Enter Company Ticker", value=''),
              dcc.Input(id='input-2-state', type='text', placeholder="Enter Company Name", value=''),
              dcc.Link(' Get Analytics ', href='/apps/app1')], id='input_fields'),
    html.Div(id='display-page'),

], style={"margin-left": "5%", "margin-right": "5%"})


@app.callback(Output('display-page', 'children'),
              Output('input_fields', 'children'),
              [Input('url', 'pathname')],
              Input(component_id='input-1-state', component_property='value'),
              Input(component_id='input-2-state', component_property='value'))
def display_page(pathname, ticker, company):
    if pathname == '/apps/app1':

        # generate links
        linkGenerator.generateLinks(ticker, company)

        # starting crawler
        startingCrawlerClass()

        return app1.layout, {'display': 'none'}
    else:
        return ''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the return statement of the `else` clause in your callback. Your callback expects two callback outpus, but you're returning one (i.e. the single empty string).

If you run the app in debug mode Dash will tell you this and also what it wants you to return instead:

> dash.exceptions.InvalidCallbackReturnValue: The callback ..display-page.children...input_fields.children.. is a multi-output.
> Expected the output type to be a list or tuple but got: ''.

So you could do something like this instead:

```
@app.callback(
    Output("display-page", "children"),
    Output("input_fields", "style"),
    [Input("url", "pathname")],
    Input(component_id="input-1-state", component_property="value"),
    Input(component_id="input-2-state", component_property="value"),
)
def display_page(pathname, ticker, company):
    if pathname == "/apps/app1":
        return app1.layout, {"display": "none"}
    else:
        return '', {'display': 'block'}
```

So the above example returns a tuple of two elements. Each element correspons to a callback output. Also the output of the `input-field` is `style`

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that, Also i was missing component-property for input-field, adjusted that in your answer. Thanks for your answer, much appreciated :)